# Realm exception "nested transaction not allowed" even though there are no nested transactions

Tags: android, realm

Recently I started a android app project. And I needed to manage data as structured as possible.

So I select the Realm and some tinker about it.

But I faced some error. But I don't know why this error happens.

The error is

**Nested transactions are not allowed. Use commitTransaction() after each beginTransaction().**

My code is in below.

```
public class CuratorApplication extends Application {

    private Realm realm;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e("debug", "Application class create!!");
        configureRealmDatabase(this);
    }

    private void configureRealmDatabase(Context context){
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .name("curator.realm")
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    }
}
```

I register realm at the Application class as described in [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#configuring-a-realm)

And I tried to transaction at the activity. But it shows error. :(

```
package com.nolgong.curator.screen;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.nolgong.curator.R;
import com.nolgong.curator.model.retrofit.Game;
import com.nolgong.curator.model.retrofit.GameInformation;
import com.nolgong.curator.model.retrofit.Team;
import com.nolgong.curator.network.NetworkClient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.exceptions.RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class IntroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button confirmBtn;
    private EditText confirmText;
    private Realm realm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);
        setUp();
        registerListener();
    }

    private String getProperty() throws IOException{
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.config));
        String property = properties.getProperty("serverAddress");
        Log.e("debug", "Property : " + property);
        return property;
    }

    private void setNetworkClient(String serverAddress){
        Log.e("debug", "Address : " + serverAddress);
        NetworkClient.getInstance(serverAddress);
    }

    private void setUp(){
        try {
            setNetworkClient(getProperty());
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("debug", "set network" + e);
        }
        confirmBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.intro_confirm);
        confirmText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.intro_input);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        Log.e("debug", "transaction state : " + realm.isInTransaction());
        Log.e("debug", "CONFIGURATION : \n" + realm.getConfiguration());
    }

    private void registerListener(){
        confirmBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String teamId = confirmText.getText().toString();
                Integer digit = Integer.valueOf(teamId);
                Log.e("debug", digit + "");
                NetworkClient.getInstance().login(digit, new Callback<GameInformation>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<GameInformation> call, Response<GameInformation> response) {
                        int responseCode = response.code();
                        switch (responseCode){
                            case 200:
                                GameInformation gameInformation = response.body();

                                Log.e("debug", "game information " + gameInformation.toString());

                                Game game = gameInformation.getGame();
                                Team team = gameInformation.getTeam();

                                updateGameToRealm(game);
                                updateTeamToRealm(team);
                                break;
                            default:
                                Log.e("debug", "Maybe something happened.");
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<GameInformation> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("debug", "Login fail :" + t.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateGameToRealm(Game game){

        com.nolgong.curator.model.database.Game rGame = new com.nolgong.
                curator.model.database.Game(game.getId(), game.getDate(),
                game.getSession(), game.getRunningTime());
        realm.beginTransaction();

        try {
            realm.copyToRealm(rGame);
        } catch (RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException e){
            Log.e("debug", e.toString());
            realm.cancelTransaction();
        } finally {
            realm.commitTransaction();
        }
    }

    private void updateTeamToRealm(Team team){
        com.nolgong.curator.model.database.Team rTeam = new com.nolgong.
                curator.model.database.Team(team.getId(), team.getMembers(),
                team.getGameId(), team.isClientDataSynced(),
                team.getJob(), team.getDigit(),
                team.getPoint());
        realm.beginTransaction();
        try {
            realm.copyToRealm(rTeam);
        } catch (RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException e){
            Log.e("debug", e.toString());
            realm.cancelTransaction();
        } finally {
            realm.commitTransaction();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Why realm shows error? Did I use it correctly? or It's just a bug? 
Please help me ioi..

Comment: Can you show the code related to the error?

Comment: You're calling `beginTransaction()` **twice** in a row **somewhere** in your code that you did not quote here.

Comment: If you have a loop somewhere, please beginTransaction outside the loop then commit after the loop is finished; also using a regular for() loop instead of foreach

Comment: @Eenvincible technically `foreach` works fine now on RealmResults now since 0.89.0 enabled "proper iteration behavior", but yes.

Comment: Oops! I forgot to change the code. Now I changed the source code.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks. But I didn't invoke beginTransaction() twice before commitTransaction()

Comment: I see that now - are you using Realm 1.1.0?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes. I use Realm 1.1.0

Answer (score 2):

As the error says,

> Nested transactions are not allowed. Use commitTransaction() after each beginTransaction().

It means that you can't do something like this:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
...
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.commitTransaction();
```

A `beginTransaction()` call must be followed by either a `commitTransaction()` or a `cancelTransaction()` call.

It's also highly recommended to use `executeTransaction()` instead of `begin/cancel/commit`, because it's easier to use, and handles cancel on exceptions for you automatically.

**EDIT:** You should not commit a transaction after it's been rolled back with `cancelTransaction()`.

Please try replacing `begin/cancel/commit` with `executeTransaction()` and see what happens.

Also, you can try replacing `copyToRealm()` with `copyToRealmOrUpdate()`.

I think you might be running into [this issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3002) because of the multiple transactions on the UI thread where you ran into a failure, but I'm actually not sure about that.

**EDIT2:**

```
private void updateGameToRealm(Game game){
    Realm realm = null;
    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        final com.nolgong.curator.model.database.Game rGame = new com.nolgong.
            curator.model.database.Game(game.getId(), game.getDate(),
            game.getSession(), game.getRunningTime());
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(rGame);
            }
        });
    } finally {
        if(realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
}

private void updateTeamToRealm(Team team){
    Realm realm = null;
    try {      
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        final com.nolgong.curator.model.database.Team rTeam = new com.nolgong.
            curator.model.database.Team(team.getId(), team.getMembers(),
            team.getGameId(), team.isClientDataSynced(),
            team.getJob(), team.getDigit(),
            team.getPoint());
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(rTeam);
            }
        });
    } finally {
        if(realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't use beginTrasaction() twice before commitTransaction(). So that's why I confusing it.

Comment: I moved my comment into the answer

Comment: I changed begin/cancel/commit to executeTransaction(). But it also said that  `Nested transactions are not allowed. Use commitTransaction() after each beginTransaction().`   I changed the transaction code as you said.

Comment: `realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm tRealm) {
            com.nolgong.curator.model.database.Game rGame = new com.nolgong.
                    curator.model.database.Game(game.getId(), game.getDate(),
                    game.getSession(), game.getRunningTime());

            tRealm.copyToRealm(rGame);
        }
    });`

Comment: Thanks Epic! I finally got the error. In other part of the code activity closed with out transaction closed. When I change the code style you recommend, I solve the problem!!

Comment: Ah, so `onDestroy()` closed the Realm instance you were trying to execute the transaction on? That's still a strange issue, you should have got `This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable.` In that case, I'll modify the code accordingly (**added to EDIT2**)

Answer (score 1):

Issue here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/542

Your realm transaction code should look similar to this:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

                    //Writing to Realm with Transaction blocks
                    realm.beginTransaction();

                    ModelClass modelClass = realm.createObject(ModelClass.class);

                    // increment index
                    long nextID = (long) (realm.where(ModelClass.class).max("id"));
                    long primaryKeyValue = nextID + 1;

                    try {
                        modelClass.setId(primaryKeyValue);
                        //your can set other values
                        realm.commitTransaction();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Realm Error", "error" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        realm.cancelTransaction();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me best solution is to start the realm transaction in 
realm.executeTransactionAsync method
relam handles the begin transaction , commit transaction itself , if you use this executeTransactionAsync method

I was also geting the same error while inserting or updating the data , then i found this method ,
below is the sample how i used

public void saveUserInfo(final UserDto userDto){

```
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(userDto);
            //realm.commitTransaction();
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new OnUserSaveEvent(true));
            realm.close();
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            realm.close();
        }
    });
}
```